# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1; Unable to make after clone

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

Im trying to run the eval.py to evaluate my training session. To do that I need to install the cocodataset (see the error message below). This is where the error occurs.

I've tried

- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
- uninstalling and re-installing cython, gcc, numpy

It seems to me that there are a lot of errors regarding gcc, which leads me to think that my error might not be related to the cocodataset, but maybe my packages or environment variables. I need advice/directions on how to solve the problem or possibly where to look. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

System Info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc

Running on AWS Deep Learning AMIs
```

Error

```
git clone https://github.com/pdollar/coco.git
Cloning into 'coco'...
remote: Counting objects: 927, done.
remote: Total 927 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 927
Receiving objects: 100% (927/927), 11.68 MiB | 3.14 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (554/554), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

(tensorflow_p27) ubuntu@remoteip:~/tmp$ cd coco/PythonAPI/

(tensorflow_p27) ubuntu@remoteip:~/tmp/coco/PythonAPI$ make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling pycocotools/_mask.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing pycocotools/_mask.pyx
running build_ext
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycocotools
creating build/common
gcc -pthread -B /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I../common -I/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/include/python2.7 -c pycocotools/_mask.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycocotools/_mask.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
gcc -pthread -B /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I../common -I/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/include/python2.7 -c ../common/maskApi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/../common/maskApi.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/compiler_compat -L/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycocotools/_mask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/../common/maskApi.o -L/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib -lpython2.7 -o /home/ubuntu/tmp/coco/PythonAPI/pycocotools/_mask.so
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

As you see above I get the following **error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Do you finished install gcc? I think you should check it, I have some error when make coco lib, and I just realized that something wrong with the hosts contains some gcc packages.
Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get gcc
```

And make sure that you have successfully install gcc.

Comment: This did not work. I ended up using a preconfigured and installed image that came with the necessities installed.